# What is the most effective way to compare strings using python in two very large files?

Tags: python, time-complexity

I have two large text files with about 10k lines in each. Each line has a unique string in the same position that needs to be compared with all the other strings in the other file to see if it matches and if not, print it out. I'm not sure how to do this in a way that makes sense time wise since the files are so large. Heres an example of the files.

```
File 1:

https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/10185/
https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/10189/
https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/10220/
https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/10217/
https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/10218/
https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/10219/
https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/10216/


file 2:

EXPLOIT:10201   CVE-2009-4781
EXPLOIT:10216   CVE-2009-4223
EXPLOIT:10217   CVE-2009-4779
EXPLOIT:10218   CVE-2009-4082
EXPLOIT:10220   CVE-2009-4220
EXPLOIT:10226   CVE-2009-4097
```

I want to check if the numbers at the end of the first file match any of the numbers after EXPLOIT:

Comment: 10k lines like those above doesn't seem that large to me. Surely you should be able to just iterate through both files at the same time and compare lines? If they aren't in the same order you could sort the lines in each file first, or use a dict/set?

Comment: What have you attempted so far? This seems like a fairly simple problem that has much help on SO for each step of the way.

Comment: @MadPhysicist honestly iterating through it isnt a problem for me to write, I just wasnt sure what was too large to be using basic loops

Comment: With strings of that length, 10k lines is only about 0.5Mb. It isn't worth spending any time trying to optimise it. Just do whatever works (e.g. using sets).

Answer (score 0):

as others have said, 10k lines aren't a problem for computers that have gigabytes of memory.  the important steps are:

1. figure out how to get the identifier out of lines in the first file
2. and again, but for the second file
3. put them together to loop over lines in each file and produce your output

regular expressions are for working with text like this, I get regexes that look like `/([0-9]+)/$` and `:([0-9]+)` for the two files (services like https://regex101.com/ are great for playing)

you can put these together in Python by doing:

```
from sys import stderr
import re

# collect all exploits for easy matching
exploits = {}
for line in open('file_2'):
  m = re.search(r':([0-9]+) ', line)
  if not m:
    print("couldn't find an id in:", repr(line), file=stderr)
    continue
  [id] = m.groups()
  exploits[id] = line

# match them up
for line in open('file_1'):
  m = re.search(r'/([0-9]+)/$', line)
  if not m:
    print("couldn't find an id in:", repr(line), file=stderr)
    continue
  [id] = m.groups()
  if id in exploits:
    pass # print(line, 'matched with', exploits[id])
  else:
    print(line)
```

Comment: I like this solution, but I think the file=stderr throws a syntax error, at least in python 2.7.

Comment: [Python 2.7 is dying](https://pythonclock.org/) I'd move away from it if you can!  you could put `from __future__ import print_function` at the top if you really want to keep using it

Comment: Right exactly. Is there anything else in this snippet that doesnt work in python 2?

Comment: looks like there is one error here:       m = re.search(r':([0-9]+) ')
TypeError: search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Comment: @bills I'd not tried running the code, it was just typed into the answer...  have added in `line` to a couple of places and it works for me now